# Tabs and Collapsible on same page

Tags: javascript, html

I am a teacher and I am trying to create a curriculum + resource website for my students, but I am having some problems and could really appreciate some help.

I am trying to use both tabs and collapsible on the same page, but I think my script's are interacting with each other, but I am not quite sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am still just starting on journey learning web design, so I still am running into hiccups quite regularly.

https://jsbin.com/talegesiqi/1/edit?html,output

```
<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();


 // Collapsible
 var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
 var x;

  for (x = 0; x < coll.length; x++)  {
 coll[x].addEventListener("select", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("open");
  var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
  content.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
  content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
  } 
  });
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should try to describe what the effect is. Is nothing happening at all? Is something unexpected happening? Perhaps there's something in the error console?

Comment: @Evert Right now nothing is happening at all. And I didn't see anything in the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a few erros when running your code, (the first on was "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null").

Well, I simplify your code a little bit:

```js
var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");

for (let x = 0; x < coll.length; x++)  {
  coll[x].onclick=function (){
    const openCol="#"+this.getAttribute('data-collapsible');
    
    
    document.querySelectorAll(openCol).classList.toggle("open");
  }
}
```

I changed getElementsByClassName to querySelectorAll because i think its a more simple approach (you will create a array too, but selecting as a CSS selector).

On your loop, it's more easy create a onclick listener, then, when you click on a .collapsible, it will check the attribute data-collapsible (I added that), this will be the ID of the element you want to show. This way you can put it anywhere on the page.

Finally on the element you want to show, it should has the ID you set on data-collapsible (in this case i set "col01" but you could use anything you want). This way, you can have multiples .collapsible.

The last problem is on your CSS, you did right on .content, but when you added the .open class, you didn't overwrite the overflow's behavior. So, you need to do this:

```
.content.open{
   overflow: unset;
}
```

This way, only when .content is open the page will display it.

You can see it working here: https://codepen.io/grloch/pen/QWwJEOa
Hope i get the problem right.

PS, you can use Bootstrap do this, look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Comment: Gabriel, Thank you so much for the quick and detailed response! It is very easy to follow along. I really appreciate it as I am still quite an amateur and trying to pick up new things wherever I can.

Comment: If it is alright, can I also ask one more follow-up question. What would I need to change so that surrounding text moves down after opening the collapsible. For example, if I move the collapsible into the middle of the page.

Comment: Don't worry, I know the fell, you was on the right way, but get a little bit lost.

Comment: You need to overwirte max-height property, you set it as 0, so, when you display it, it still 0.

Add "max-height: unset" to .content.open and it will fix.